# SQL Server : stored procedure to have optional parameter

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, option-type

How do we specify default parameters for stored procedures?

I have seen the following two options.

Option 1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(@dataOne INT, @dataTwo INT = DEFAULT)
```

Option 2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(@dataOne INT, @dataTwo INT = 3)
```

I have used this stored procedure with one single parameter in some places of my C# code. Now I want to use it with one optional parameter. I want to make sure that the optional parameter will have a default value too.

Any help please? Where have I gone wrong ?

I used the above 2 methods. But it did not work. I did not get a default value.

Comment: are you sending the parameter from code behind which is default ?

Comment: No... I want the default to be set in the Stored Procedure itself.

Comment: The default value of a parameter is only used if you do not send that parameter at all. Just don't send the parameter from code behind if you want to use the default value.

Answer (score 4):

The default value of a parameter is only used if you do not send that parameter at all. Just don't send the parameter from code behind if you want to use the default value.
Use `CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(@dataOne INT,@dataTwo INT=3)..`
and don't send `@dataTwo` from code behind, then 3 will be used as the default value.
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Shaminder S Aujla, default value only be used when value won't be passed.

demo test code:

***Create Procedure***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]
        @dataOne            Int
    ,@dataTwo           Int = 3
As
Begin

    Set Nocount On;

    ----TSQL Statements

    ----TODO: remove after 'optional parameter works perfectly' get confirmed
    ----testing optional parameter from MSSQL Management Studio itself
    Select   @dataOne As CompulsaryParameterValue
            ,@dataTwo As OptionalParameterValue

End
```

***Testing procedure***

```
---- testing with default value
Exec dbo.myProcedure @dataOne = 5;

---- testing with passed value
Exec dbo.myProcedure @dataOne = 5, @dataTwo = 7;
```

***Dropping procedure once testing done***

```
---- drop as testing done.
Drop Procedure dbo.myProcedure;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting default value for a parameter in CREATE PROCEDURE command, set the value in a separate SQL statement. This SQL statement will be included in your stored procedure definition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(@dataOne INT,@dataTwo INT)
AS
IF(@dataTwo IS NULL OR @dataTwo = '')
BEGIN
   SET @dataTwo = 3 --(your default value)
END
```

**Advantage:** If you want to use other than default value for your '@dataTwo' parameter, you don't need to worry again to change definition of your stored procedure.